# how can i make a .jar executable + I'm on ubuntu Studio 13.10

Tags: java, minecraft

how do i make my mine craft executable.Ive tried running it in terminal and many forum answers. when I get to mine craft and i go into properties. and i look for allow to execute it doesn't appear i have no option to make it executable. I suppose i must
do it in the terminal yet i do not have the extra time for reading this whole thing Java -h
please help me get a quick easy or hard answer. <----- Original
Ive done what someone in the comments said and i got my computer to recognize it as a .jar 
but it still won't  work i tried a very very helpful forum and learned some stuff but still nothing please help me guys i am stuck

Comment: a simple web search for 'minecraft ubuntu' gives several results with step by step instructions. If you want to use this site as a resource you must be willing to do some work and research on your own first.

Comment: look i have searched every corner of the inter net i have even used unrelated forum topics and changed some of the terminal properties i don't want to search any more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a shortcut for Minecraft like in Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/566153/how-to-create-a-shortcut-for-minecraft-like-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I always run it via. command line:

```
java -jar /path/to/minecraft.jar
```

You could create a short script called `start_minecraft.sh` with the following contents:

```
#/bin/bash
/usr/bin/java -jar /path/to/minecraft.jar
```

and chmod +x the file.

Comment: i think you're the best person ever for answering but it wont let me it says unable to access /path/to/minecraft.jar help

Comment: You'll have to figure out where the minecraft.jar file is stored and update the path in my example. This would be the file you downloaded from Mojang (with a similar, but possibly not the exact same name).

Comment: can you help me find this name it isn,t neccesarily easy to find

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Launcher using the commands, it's easy and simple!

Right-Click
Click Create launcher and fill in the command and directory, also change "minecraft.jar" to "Minecraft.jar" as that's what it's called for 1.9

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)