# How to create a shortcut for Minecraft like in Windows?

Tags: java, minecraft

I downloaded Minecraft. I created a 'Portable Apps' directory under Home. I then right-clicked 'Minecraft.jar' and selected 'Make Link'.

I then moved the "shortcut" to the desktop.

When I try to launch Minecraft from that shortcut, I either get errors or Minecraft saves a whole bunch of random data files to the desktop.

Why can't Ubuntu create proper shortcuts like Windows? Why does it treat shortcuts like actual programs? Why isn't a "Link" a link? Why is it the actual program?

Comment: Read this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/450266/an-easy-way-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut

Comment: Don't complain about the system just because you don't understand how to use it.

Comment: yes as @cremefraiche has stated Windows and Linux are not the same system. Ubuntu uses unity which abides by the open desktop standards, where as Windows does its own thing.

Comment: @gyropyge and all other fanboys: I never said "Why isn't Ubuntu like Windows?", I said "Why can't Ubuntu create _proper_ shortcuts _like_ Windows?" Big difference there. I wouldn't have ditched an operating system (Windows) that I've been using and programming for for over 10 years in favor of Ubuntu if I wanted Ubuntu to "be like" Windows.

Comment: @William You either didn't read my question or you didn't read the answer you linked to, because the top-rated answer in your link is *exactly* what I said I did in my question.

Comment: I also notice this strange behavior sometimes, which is perhaps rooted in Gnome or Debian or even Linux (I'm just making an uneducated guess here). The way a symbolic link is treated does not seem consistent system-wide (all apps behaving in the same way) at the moment.

Comment: Just for clarification, Wikipedia explains the difference between [Windows shortcut files and POSIX symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Shortcuts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way to use a portable app like this under Ubuntu requires also creating a "*.desktop" file for its executable (which is "**Minecraft.jar**" in this case), and putting it in one of these folders: `/usr/share/applications`, `/usr/local/share/applications`, or `/home/jay/.local/share/applications` (which looks like the one you would prefer).

If you want a "shortcut" for this app on your desktop as well, you should simply **copy that "*.desktop" file to your desktop**. It's OK to create shortcuts for files, folders, and other places, but it's not advisable to do the same for apps in this case.

Here's a sample file, which you might name as "**minecraft.desktop**", which is simply a plain text file given **executable** permissions.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Minecraft
Comment=Java minecraft game
Exec="/home/jay/Portable Apps/Minecraft.jar"
Icon="/home/jay/Portable Apps/Minecraft.png"
Categories=Games;
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
```

It's assumed above that your user name is **jay** and you also have an icon file named "**Minecraft.png**", otherwise you should better have one.

Comment: Oh I get it now! Thanks so much @sadi this worked perfectly.

Comment: @jay_t55 : You're welcome, please don't be put off by people who are not patient enough towards ex-Windows users who have newly begun using Ubuntu/Linux and who naturally might have difficulties from time to time in discovering this new world with all its pros and cons ;-)

Comment: On my system, I had to do: `Exec=java -jar ./Downloads/Minecraft/Minecraft.jar` where I put my Minecraft.jar file in my `Downloads/Minecraft/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Does the original 'Minecraft.jar' work correctly? I'm thinking that maybe there is a problem in how Ubuntu is handling your .jar files. If that's the problem, read [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192914/how-run-a-jar-file-with-a-double-click).

I have tried two methods to make desktop shortcuts: the *right click* → *make link* and *right click* → *copy to*.  I mostly use *copy to* for the executable files usually found on `/usr/share/applications`. I know that *copy to* doesn't really create a shortcut, but it does the job for me.